# How to cast null to 0 in groovy scripting

Tags: groovy

I am trying to create a sum but I want to cast all of the `null` values as `0` values so that it can perform the sum. However I am receiving this error;

```
Cannot cast object '[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]'
  with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'int'
```

How can I cast all nulls into 0?

Below is the code I have:

```
 def resultSearchCostGroup = json.xxx.xxx.xxx.search
    int totalSearchCostGroup = json.xxx.xxx.xxx.search.collectMany{ it ?: 0 }.sum()
    log.info resultSearchCostGroup
```

Comment: do-something with series, seems ideal candidate for closure? Cant help with code, for me is too less details to imagine

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use `collectMany`? Would it be possible to show the json?

Comment: Can you post a correct JSON?

Comment: Posted full json in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your you can just `flatten` your collection and then `collect` to replace nulls?

```
json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.flatten().collect{it?:0}.sum()
```

Comment: Hi Randall, does it mean I have to set it as a property even if i only require it as a check? Because I'm getting a no such property it for class error

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give example?

Comment: No such property: it for class: Script1 - this is the error I receive when I replace my line of code with your line of code and i'm not sure what I need to do to fix this error

Comment: It's hard to tell whats the problem without full code. You can try to replace `it` with named argument, like this:
`json.products.costGroups.costLines.search.flatten().collect{search -> search?:0}.sum()`